# nested repeaters - how to sort

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table: **Category** with some sort of categories

```
 category1 
 category2
 category3
```

I have another table **Subcategory** which has a fk to Category.
So, each category1 can have *subcategoryB, subcategoryA, subcategoryZ*.

Well... i've made two repeaters.
The first one is binded to a linq data source which takes the categories from the parent table.

The children repeater is binded to that foreign key like:

```
DataSource='<%# Eval("Subcategories_1s") %>'
```

So the result is:

```
category1
   subcategoryB
   subcategoryA
   subcategoryZ
category2
```

etc.
Well, the strange question is: **how can i order the subcategories alphabetically?**
If i'd have binded the children repeater to a linq it would be easy.
But in this case...?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with [this](http://www.hawkfield.be/articles.php/Nesting_repeaters_in_.NET) example !

Of course, no more linq data source, automatically binded, but used DataSet and relations. Check the above link for further informations.

Comment: You say you solved this problem? I'm currently stuck in the same problem although I'm using nested gridviews. How were you able to get the sort to work?